# Integrate tabhost and navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-navigation

In my app, I'm using a tabhost and navigation drawer together. However, if I press an item in a navigation drawer, it launch a fragment, but the tabhost not change to the corresponding tab. I would like to fix this but I dont know how.

This picture explain the structure of my app and my problem:

> [image]

Comment: please go with https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/AndroidSideMenu and http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-tutorial-fragments/

Comment: Hi, I'm using navigation drawer by google and tabhost, and it works well. The problem is that if I press an item in a navigation drawer, I would like that the tab in tabhost must be selected from.

Comment: oh ok..i will look in similar code snap and will reply you.

Comment: just update it manually, you know when an item was selected in the navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

code snippet from fragment: this will change the tab when button is clicked

```
((MenuActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentTab(<tabnumber>);
```

code snippet from menu activity

```
public void setCurrentTab(int argTabIndex){
            mTabHelper.setCurrentTab(argTabIndex);
        }
```

Following actionbarcompat example.

https://github.com/antoniolg/ActionBarCompatExample